# Show for all real $u,v,w$: $\left|u+v\right|+\left|u+w\right|+\left|w+v\right|\le\left|u\right|+\left|v\right|+\left|w\right|+\left|u+v+w\right|$

Tags: vectors

Show that for all vectors $u,v,w \in \mathbb R^3$:
$$\left|u+v\right|+\left|u+w\right|+\left|w+v\right|\le\left|u\right|+\left|v\right|+\left|w\right|+\left|u+v+w\right|$$
I know that we should show that :
$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(u_{i}+v_{i}\right)^{2}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(u_{i}+w_{i}\right)^{2}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(w_{i}+v_{i}\right)^{2}}$$$$\le\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(u_{i}\right)^{2}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(v_{i}\right)^{2}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(w_{i}\right)^{2}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(u_{i}+v_{i}+w_{i}\right)^{2}}$$

Is that right?

But this way looks a little difficult and takes much time,does there any other way?

Comment: If this helps, geometrically they are diagonals and sides in parallelepiped.

Answer (score 4):

One can show by a straightforward (yet tedious) calculation that the following holds for $u,v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n:$

$$ |u|+|v|+|w|-|u+v|-|v+w|-|w+u|+|u+v+w|=\frac{\sum_{\text{cyc}}(|v|+|w|-|v+w|)\cdot(|u|-|v+w|+|u+v+w|)}{|u|+|v|+|w|+|u+v+w|}$$

Evidently, the right-hand side is non-negative because of the triangle inequality. The desired result follows.

$\textbf{Note}$
The "cyc" subscript indicates that the sum is a "cyclic" sum; Suppose we have a cyclic sum as follows:
$$S:=\sum_{\text{cyc}} \:f(a,b,c)$$
Then, $S=f(a,b,c)+ f(b,c,a)+ f(c,a,b)$. A cyclic sum cycles through all the arguments of the summand and then takes the sum of its values.

Comment: subtract $\frac{1}{3}|u+v|$ from both side and multiply both side by $3/2$. Then analogously write down $|u+w|$ and $|w+v|$ and add them.

Comment: @45465, I have edited my answer.

Comment: I have included an explanation. The starting equation can be proved by directly expanding both sides after multiplying through by the denominator of the RHS